# Gatsby: How to clone a node with new type?

Tags: gatsby

In my blog I have blog post data from two sources, old json files (-> `PostJson` GraphQL nodes) and new .md files (-> `MarkdownRemark` nodes). They both have the same data but different keys / structure.

To simplify page creation, I would like to "wrap" each of them with a new node type, `BlogPost` with the same structure as `MarkdownRemark`. Is there a simple way to do it?

In pseudocode:

`if(type == MarkdownRemark) 
  cloneNodeWithType({parent: node, type: "BlogPost", fields: {..node, ..node.fields}) 
else if (type==PostJson) 
  createNode({parent: node, type: "BlogPost", fields: {slug: node.permalink, html: node.content, ...})`

To clone the node I guess I need to do (for the Remark node):

`createNode({ node: {
      id: "str",
      parent: node,
      internal: {
        mediaType: "text/html",
        type: "ContentPage",
        content: node.content,
        contentDigest: node.contentDigest
      },
      fields: {
        ..node.fields
      }
    }})`

Right?

So:
1. Is this a good solution to the problem?
2. How to clone a node?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

That is right and it works but there is one more challenge - extra "dynamic" fields added to the node by plugins via Gatsby's [`setFieldsOnGraphQLNodeType`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/#setFieldsOnGraphQLNodeType) because 1) these might not be there yet upon `onCreateNode` and 2) often these are not values but functions such as [Remarks'](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/b7d4656f9cffbcfbdfad5466242c407b64d66be0/packages/gatsby-transformer-remark/src/extend-node-type.js) `html()` or `excerpt(pruneLength: ...)`. These you just need copy and paste (or [import and reuse as I did](https://github.com/holyjak/blog.jakubholy.net/blob/c87b7db133a96ba1b116f33246a98c805fa9a501/gatsby-node.js#L166)).